# Cannot connect to AD LDS with SSL using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, adam, adlds

If I query my AD LDS instance with powershell using my credentials it works great using this code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * `
-SearchBase 'OU=Groups,DC=dev,DC=net' `
-Server 'myserver.mydomain:389'
```

However when I try connect to the AD LDS instance using SSL by specifying the port 636, I just get the error message:

`Get-ADUser : Server instance not found on the given port`

Here is the updated (not working) code for ssl/port 636:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * `
-SearchBase 'OU=Groups,DC=dev,DC=net' `
-Server 'myserver.mydomain:636'
```

As a contrast, connecting to the instance using C# works fine using this code (from the same computer as from which I tried the powereshell script):

```
using(var ctx = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, 
            "myserver.mydomain:636", 
            "OU=Groups,DC=dev,DC=net",
             ContextOptions.Negotiate
                | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer 
                | ContextOptions.ServerBind)
) {
    var up = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    var searchForUser = new PrincipalSearcher(up);
    searchForUser.FindAll()
}
```

What am I missing to connect to my AD LDS instance using SSL in powershell?

Comment: Did you set it up? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725767(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Yes, I've read the article. The SSL connection works when I connect with LDP.exe like it says in the article. It also works when I connect using c# code. The trouble seems to get the SSL connection to work with powershell